# Mapping Proof Abstract Algebra (HW)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that there is a mapping from a set to itself that is one-to-one
>   but not onto iff there is a mapping from the set to itself that is
>   onto but not one-to-one.

I'm trying to argue that the order of the sets cannot be correct, but I don't understand how there has to be a two different mappings instead of just one.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of the  sets cannot be correct"?
In particular, there is just one set mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong idea. I'm not really sure. But a 1-1 mapping always means an element has to map to a unique one, and to be "not onto" means that not every element is mapped to. So if every element has to be unique, but not every element is mapped to, the order must be |S| + 1 at least.

Comment: The order of *what* must be at least $|S|+1$? The order of $S$? But the order of $S$ is $|S|$. So, how can $|S|$ be at least $|S|+1$? Therein lies the answer.

Comment: I'm new to proofs, how would I write that out? Would that be a contradiction?

Comment: Have you heard about *infinite sets*?

Comment: @Lilluda5 start with what you're given. Assume that $f:S \rightarrow S$ is one-to-one but not onto. Can you construct a $g:S \rightarrow S$ from $f$ that is onto?

Comment: Yes, and I realize that being one-to-one, but not onto is the definition of an infinite set. However, I still don't understand how to piece this together to prove my statement.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:S\to S$ be one-to-one but not onto. Let $X:=S\setminus f(S) \ne \emptyset$.

Then define $g:S\to S$ such that if $s\in f(S)$ then ??? 
and if $s\in X$ then ???. And it will be onto but not one-to-one.

The other direction can be done similarly.

Comment: ... can be done similarly with the axiom of choice (which is obviously to be assumed here).

Comment: @Berci for your first question mark, i came up with "then g(s) is not contained in f(s)" and for the second one "g(s) is contained in X" is that correct?

Comment: first ???: let $g(s):=f^{-1}(s)$ which is unique due to the one-to-one requirement.  second ???: let $g(s):=s_0$ a fixed (but arbitrary) element $s_0\in S$.
..@Brian, yes indeed, AC is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is perhaps easier to imagine that you have *two* sets, both nonempty, and then find an argument that there exists a one-to-one but not onto $f:A\to B$ exactly if there exists an onto but not-one-to-one $g:B\to A$.

Once you have proved that, it will still be true in the case that $A$ and $B$ happen to be identical. (And then the existence of a function $S\to S$ that is either "not onto" or "not one-to-one" will imply that $S$ is not empty).

Comment: So with this, I've come up with B mapping to one element in A. This would be an example of something that is onto, but not 1-1 right?

Comment: @Lilluda: You mean every element in $B$ maps to the _same_ element of $A$? That won't be onto, unless $A$ has only one element.

Comment: What if i define $g:B\to A$ s.t. g(x) =f(x) if x is an element of f(x) otherwise g(x) = x. Wouldn't that be onto?

Comment: @Lilluda: Are you assuming $f:A\to B$? Then what you're trying to define here won't even be $B\to A$ because you define $g(x)$ to be either $f(x)$ or $x$, both of which are in $B$ rather than in $A$. And $f(x)$ makes no sense if $x$ is in $B$ because the domain of $f$ is $A$ not $B$.

Comment: can you provide more insight... i still haven't figured this out